# install homebrew required root password

Tags: macos, homebrew

I try to install homebrew at

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(/usr/bin/curl -fksSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/master/Library/Contributions/install_homebrew.rb)"
```

but it required root password

```
    ==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod g+rwx /usr/local/. /usr/local/bin /usr/local/include /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig /usr/local/share /usr/local/share/man /usr/local/share/man/man1

WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.

Password:
```

But I did not set any password on my mac.

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't requiring the root password. The message is about `sudo`, which requires the password for a user with administrator rights. Try just using the password for your user account.

Answer (score 0):

Most UNIX operating systems have the root user disabled with a blank password.
If you would offer more details about your OS I can give you the info you require to set the password.