# Homebrew Password Prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, homebrew

Hi I'm trying set up my Mac to run Ruby on Rails but Im stuck trying to install Homebrew and also RVM.

When I type into the terminal:

```
 ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

It returns it returns the usual block of text and at the end where it shows:

```
 WARNING: Improper use of the sudo command could lead to data loss
 or the deletion of important system files. Please double-check your
  typing when using sudo. Type "man sudo" for more information.

 To proceed, enter your password, or type Ctrl-C to abort.

Password:
```

When I try to type In my root password nothing happens, the only input that returns something is pressing the enter key which comes back with the message 'Sorry, try again.'

The same thing happens when I try to run the install for RVM:

```
  Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
  Found remote file https://rvm.io/binaries/osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.bz2
  Checking requirements for osx.
  Installing  macports.................................................................................................................
 ..............................................................
     connorashton password required for 'make install': .......
```

It again wont let me type anything In. Also may be of note that instead of showing the text cursor it just has a small grey rectangle.

Any help greatly appreciated!

<------- Edit ------->

Thanks for your comments I've finally got things moving and have now passed the passwords prompts. However RVM is now coming back with another error:

```
  Downloaded archive checksum did not match, archive was removed!
  If you wish to continue with not matching download add '--verify-downloads 2' after 
   the          command.

  Downloading https://rvm.io/binaries/osx/10.9/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p247.tar.bz2 failed.
   Mounting remote ruby failed, trying to compile.
    connorashton password required for 'softwareupdate -l':
```

So i re-entered my password and it started running again but then came back with:

```
   Retrieving rubygems-2.1.11
   There is no checksum for 'http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-     
     2.1.11.tgz' 
     or 'rubygems-2.1.11.tgz', it's not possible to validate it.
    This could be because your RVM install's list of versions is out of date. 
      You may want    to
     update your list of rubies by running 'rvm get stable' and try again.
    If that does not resolve the issue and you wish to continue with unverified download
     add '--verify-downloads 1' after the command.

     There has been an error while trying to fetch rubygems. 
      Halting the installation.
```

Sorry for the questions I just want to get this thing up and running!

Comment: possible duplicate of [install homebrew required root password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281560/install-homebrew-required-root-password)

Comment: Hi I read that post before creating my own but didn't get any answers from it. Im running it on the main administrator account (no other users on my mac) and I have also followed apple's instructions to set a root access password.

Comment: `sudo` doesn't ask for your `root` password, but for the password of the current account. Have you tried that? (Also, that's exactly what is stated as the accepted answer in the question linked to by Ororuk)

Comment: Yes the problem is that it wont let me type anything after it prompts me for my password. Could this be caused by a problem with the Xcode Command Line Tools? I seem to be having a problem with that as well because after I had installed the command tools when I type $ gcc or $ xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools    it's coming back with 'clang: error: no input files'

Comment: `no input files` actually just means that `gcc` could not find source files to compile. To see if a command is available, you would normally as it to print its version. For most command line programs, this can be done with `[command name] -v`, sometimes also `--version` or very rarely `-V`. `gcc -v` for example will print something like `gcc version 4.7.4` along with lots of other information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` will hide the characters that you type. So it is normal that nothing shows up in the console while you type the password. Just type the password for your current account then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Also make sure that your account has administrator rights under:

```
System Preferences > Users & Groups > [Your Name] > Allow user to administer this computer
```

Comment: Thanks finally got it to go past the password prompt screen! However I've now run into another problem with RVM installation and I've added it to my original post, if you could give me some advice on that, that would be great.

Comment: @ConnorAshton the error means that the integrity of the source code could not be verified. You can run again with `--verify-downloads 1` to ignore that but a better solution would be to fix this. Have you updated RVM with `rvm get stable` as the error message suggests?

Comment: I did initially try the 'rvm get stable' but it didn't seem to do anything but it's now working after I retried it so I must have just wrote it wrong. Everything seems to be working now thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For others who may still have problems, I enabled `root` user, made my user admin, gave my user sudo privileges, but still could not get past the password prompt. Sudo privileges otherwise worked as expected (e.g., `sudo ls`).

Giving myself passwordless sudo privileges finally got me past the installation script.

Comment: enable sudo privs as mentioned here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257813/enable-sudo-without-a-password-on-macos